Weird BitTorrent peer without percentage and client id
Just now, two of the files I seed got peers downloading.
I took a peek and it looks very weird: the peers downloading
the files doesn't have a percentage information of how much
they have already downloaded.
What's more weird is that their BitTorrent client ID is
only a hash instead of a name. One of them is 8d-83cf-,
the other 6e-976e-. Looks like hex.
What's more weird is the IPs of the two peers are in the
exact same city, while the two of the torrents I'm seeding
are really different from each other, so there is very few
chance that it's the same user. But not same user, but in
same city, and same weird no-percentage and device name -
that's creepy!
My question is: why would there be such weird peer?
Are they using a specially designed client that send
no percentage information, so they can only leech,
but doesn't seed?

Update on Sep. 21: I caught two other of them named
f4-b5cf and 15-9127- respectively, and I began
to add them to my blocklist.
I also heard people say that those might be some
organisations deliberately downloading stuff from
the BitTorrent network and redirect whatever they
downloaded to /dev/null, and that's why they don't
provide the percentage information and they keep
downloading - they just don't
store anything they have downloaded.
And I found a GitHub discussion of it:
https://github.com/anacrolix/torrent/issues/889
However, I haven't found reliable source to that
opinion.
